# Jupyter notebook, where?

Tags: anaconda

I don't understand where to get this (see the link) http://forumbilder.se/H8BSE/skarmavbild-2018-10-01-kl-10-20-25

I thought that we used jupyter Notebook in IDLE/shell (I have downloaded anaconda) but this seems to be something different?

Regards,

**UPDATE:** ok, I found it, needed to type jupyter notebook in the terminal, and then the broweser came up. Thanks anyway

Comment: How that website link is related to your question and jupyter notebook?

Comment: @bhansa I want to enter it? i wanna know how to get there? since i thought that jupiter notebook was a package for python - and therefore use it in IDLE/shell.